# Equivalente ao sprintf do PHP em JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

Em vez de fazer:

```js
var html = '<a href="' + data.href + '" title="' + data.title + '">' + data.desc + '</a>';
```

Estou fazendo:

```js
var html = '<a href="{href}" title="{title}">{desc}</a>';

html = html
     .replace( '{href}',  data.href )
     .replace( '{title}', data.title )
     .replace( '{desc}',  data.desc );
```

Ou `replace( /{nome}/g, data.nome )` se houverem várias ocorrências.

Existe alguma maneira "oficial" ou cada um tem que resolver por sua conta criando uma função personalizada?

Encontrei um par de plugins antigos para jQuery, [2007](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2405455/1287812) e [2008](https://github.com/azatoth/jquery-sprintf). Mudou alguma coisa de lá para cá? Os *frameworks* JavaScript, como jQuery ou Mootools, já incorporam isso? Se sim, qual o JS por trás disso?

Comment: Existe o convenientemente batizado [sprintf.js](https://github.com/alexei/sprintf.js), apesar de não ser nativo

Comment: Eu costumo usar o construtor de elementos do MooTools para casos semelhantes ao que colocou http://jsfiddle.net/j1tknqj7/, mas acho que uma versão JS do `sprintf` não existe. Vou colocar uma sugestão quando a minha criançada estiver na cama e se ainda não houver uma boa sugestão.

Comment: Existem sistemas de template que resolvem isso. Com handlebars ou mustache, você teria `'<a href="{{href}}" title="{{title}}">{{desc}}</a>'` compilado como template, e depois só passa o objeto `data` para o template que ele resolve.

Comment: @bfavaretto, esqueci de comentar que minha inspiração veio do *bigode*. Minha intenção é algo mais básico para manipulação de strings html dentro de código js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com jQuery você pode usar seu construtor de elementos:

```
var $elemento = $("<a>", {href: data.href, title: data.title}).text(data.desc);
$('.umContainerParaNossoElemento').html($elemento);
console.log("Versão string: " + $elemento[0].outterHTML);
```

Assim, você pode construir elementos jQuery, que contém um HTMLElement. Com isso você pode manipular o elemento como registrar eventos, inserir outros elementos, etc, mesmo antes do objeto estar no documento.

Como perguntado, o primeiro elemento você passa a string da tag(s) que você quer criar como `< div>` ou `< ul>< li>`.
O segundo argumento é um objeto com os valores dos atributos da tag, em camel case (o HTML é case insensitive!), como `{href: 'valor', class: 'umaClasse', type: 'button'}`.

[Criando elementos com jQuery - jQuery API](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery2)

Comment: Que outros parâmetros posso usar no construtor? Seria legal linkar pra documentação...

Answer (score 2):

Pra sua e nossa sorte tem uma galera antenada em transformar functions do PHP em JS e você encontrará um monte no site http://phpjs.org.

A equivalente a ***sprintf*** é esta http://phpjs.org/functions/sprintf/

Boa sorte!

Answer (score 2):

No ECMAScript 6 (ES6), a última versão da especificação do JavaScript, existem as [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings), que permitem algo parecido:

```
var a = 5;
var b = 10;
console.log(`Fifteen is ${a + b} and\nnot ${2 * a + b}.`);
```

E a boa notícia: isso **já funciona** no Chrome, Firefox, Opera e no Edge.

Answer (score 1):

A minha solução para isso seria adicionando um método ao `prototype` de `String`:

```
 String.prototype.format = function()
 {
    var args = arguments;

    return this.replace(/\{(\d+)\}/g, function(text, key)
    {
        return args[key];
    });
 }
```

Daí poderíamos fazer a seguinte chamada:

```
"Meu nome é '{0}' e estou no site <strong>{1}</strong>".format('Wallace', 'StackOverlow')
```

A saída seria:

```
"Meu nome é 'Wallace' e estou no site <strong>StackOverlow</strong>
```

Eu tirei a ideia para escrever essa função da linguagem chamada `Python`.